# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/annotation/CheckForNull.class

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

I migrated my project from eclipse to Android Studio,When I'm trying to run my app,I am getting following issue

> ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/annotation/CheckForNull.class

**Here is my build.gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.le.SampleApp"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    aaptOptions
            {
                cruncherEnabled = false
            }


    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'


}

configurations {
    compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':_library')
    compile project(':drag_library')
    compile project(':library_pull')


    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.+'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.13.1-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.15.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')

    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/amazinglistview.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-io-1.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/crashlytics.jar')
    compile files('libs/d2xx.jar')

    compile files('libs/iHealthLibrary_2.2.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/paho-mqtt-client-1.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/pl2303driver.jar')
    compile files('libs/robospice-1.4.11.jar')
    compile files('libs/robospice-cache-1.4.11.jar')
    compile files('libs/robospice-google-http-client-1.4.11.jar')
    compile files('libs/rtcc-5.4.730.jar')
    compile files('libs/samsung_ble_sdk_200.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3-with-sources.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
}
```

Any advice on how i could resolve this issue?

Comment: You are adding javax/annotation/CheckForNull twice. You have a lot of jar, you should check them (and may be in same of them you can use maven dependencies instead of jar files)

Comment: how do you solve this problem?

Comment: check @Gabriele Mariotti answer.You have to check all your jar files